# weak-* versus entropy growth

Tags: pr.probability, measure-theory, ergodic-theory, entropy, symbolic-dynamics

General question. Let $\eta_{n}$ be a sequence of invariant measures on $\{0,1,2,...,p-1\}^{\mathbb{N}}$ and $B$ the Bernoulli  uniform measure. Knowing that $\eta_{n} \rightarrow B$ in the weak-* topology, this, somehow, could help me to prove that $h(\eta_{n})\rightarrow\log p$?

I know it is easy to produce zero-entropy measures that converge in the weak-* topology to $B$. What I would like to know is: having the weak-* topology more some friendly hypothesis on the measures $\eta_{n}$, could I guarantee growth of entropy?

Comment: The *finitely determined* property of a Bernoulli measure $B$ says *if* $\eta_n$ converge weakly to $B$ *and* $h(\eta_n)\to h(B)$, then $\bar d(\eta_n,B)\to 0$. This is a key part of Ornstein theory.

Comment: It's a bit hard to imagine what kind of property you could be looking for that guarantees $h(\eta_n)\to h(B)$. As you point out, no local property is sufficient. Generally it's not too hard to check that $h(\eta_n)\to h(B)$ if it's true. The conclusion of the finitely determined property is then very strong.

Comment: @Algernon: as the OP says, it's not hard to produce zero entropy invariant measures that converge to $B$. (the entropy is upper semi-continuous; not lower semi-continuous).

Comment: @Algernon: I'm not sure what you think I misread. It is *not true* that weak$^*$-convergence to the uniform Bernoulli measure gives convergence in entropy. For example, here is a construction of a measure: $\eta_n=\frac{1}{np^n}\sum_{w\in\{0,\ldots,p-1\}^n}\sum_{k=0}^{n-1}\delta_{ \sigma ^k(\bar w)}$, where $\bar w$ is the periodic point $(\bar w)_i=w_{i\bmod n}$. Obviously $h(\eta_n)=0$. It's not hard to check that $\eta_n$ converge weakly to $B$.

Comment: @AnthonyQuas, I was thinking about when a sequence of measures converge in the weak-* it will converge in the strong topology as well, I mean, \eta_{n}(A) \rightarrow B(A) for all measurable A. This is kind of an application of Dominated Convergence Theorem. But it is still nothing for me, when we have to face entropy...

Comment: Dear @AnthonyQuas, why did you say it's easy generally see that the entropy is growing? Could you give some examples, articles to take a look? I haven't found any...

Comment: So to prove that the entropy is growing, I would try and understand the distribution of $x_0$ conditional on $x_1,\ldots,x_n$. If this is approximately uniform for most $x$ and for all $n$, then the entropy is close to $\log p$.

Comment: I think it is a nice question, it is a little annoying not being able to control $h(\eta_n).$

Comment: Dear @user39115, I completely aggree with you. But, have you thought about nice examples where we can see entropy growth? Theory, papers where they deal with this... thanks a lot for your attention

Comment: In a very particular setting only. I could provide you particular examples for some families of uniformly hyperbolic maps on the unit interval and the entropy with respect to the acip. However, I am not sure how general is enough for you.

Comment: Well, @user39115, I'm interested in measure in the symbolic dynamics, as I've written. What I want is: some ideas, about how to detect that the entropy is growing, good hypothesis to make sure that entropy will grow and why... things like that. Maybe with your case, I can have some ideas...